# Check if widget exist(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to check if a widget (such as rectangle drawn on a canvas) exists before I delete it.

Here's my problem: I have two methods that delete rectangles. One is bound to button-1 using `bind` (delete the rectangle when it is clicked) and the other method deletes a rectangle if it doesn't get clicked in a certain amount of time (checked using `Widget.after`).  I would like to check if the rectangle exists in the second method because I want to count the rectangles user didn't click and the only way I can think of is check if it is already deleted.  Is there a way to do this? Of course, I could set a variable inside button-1 event handler and check it from the other method.  But just wanted to know if `Tkinter` provides method such as "item exist".

Edit : Well, I just found out one trick. If I use itemconfig on deleted widget, I get empty set. I use that value to see if a widget is already deleted or not. I'm not sure if it's an elegant way to do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that you could use [`Canvas.find_all`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) to get a tuple of all of the items on your canvas.  Then you could see if your particular item is `in` that tuple.  e.g.:

```
if item in my_canvas.find_all():
   my_canvas.delete(item)
else:
   print("Item not on canvas")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also unmap the widget with `forget` instead of destroying it so that the widget disappears but the variable name stays valid. `widget.winfo_ismapped()` will tell you if it is mapped.

```py
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> widget = tk.Label(root, text='squeamish ossifrage')
>>> widget.winfo_ismapped()
0
>>> widget.pack()
>>> widget.winfo_ismapped()
1
>>> widget.forget()
>>> widget.winfo_ismapped()
0
```

There is no problem running `widget.forget()` on an unmapped widget so you don't even need to check its status for future statements; just run `forget` or run `pack` or overwrite the variable as needed.